# jq + update json file and append name according to ID number

Tags: python, json, linux, bash, jq

We want to edit the json file according to the following rule

We need to generate the name `car0X_hyb.com`  - under `mazda`  string ( while X is the ID number )

we need to update the json file on our linux machine

Example -  `ID=1`

Then json will be as

```
{
  "toyota": [
    "car1.com"
  ],
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com"
  ],
  "ford": [
    "car01_eng.com"
  ]
}
```

`ID=4` , Then json will be as

```
{
  "toyota": [
    "car1.com"
  ],
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com",
    "car02_hyb.com",
    "car03_hyb.com",
    "car04_hyb.com"
  ],
  "ford": [
    "car01_eng.com"
  ]
}
```

`ID=6` , Then json will be as

```
{
  "toyota": [
    "car1.com"
  ],
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com",
    "car02_hyb.com",
    "car03_hyb.com",
    "car04_hyb.com",
    "car05_hyb.com",
    "car06_hyb.com"
  ],
  "ford": [
    "car01_eng.com"
  ]
}
```

`ID=10` , Then json will be as

```
{
  "toyota": [
    "car1.com"
  ],
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com",
    "car02_hyb.com",
    "car03_hyb.com",
    "car04_hyb.com",
    "car05_hyb.com",
    "car06_hyb.com",
    "car07_hyb.com",
    "car08_hyb.com",
    "car09_hyb.com",
    "car10_hyb.com"
  ],
  "ford": [
    "car01_eng.com"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please follow the [mcve] guidelines as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a stream of subsequent numbers using `range`, use them to fill the template string, and make an array out of the results, like:

```
$ jq -n --argjson ID 5 '.mazda = [ range($ID) | "car\("0\(.+1)"[-2:])_hyb.com" ]'
{
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com",
    "car02_hyb.com",
    "car03_hyb.com",
    "car04_hyb.com",
    "car05_hyb.com"
  ]
}
$ jq -n --argjson ID 10 '.mazda = [ range($ID) | "car\("0\(.+1)"[-2:])_hyb.com" ]'
{
  "mazda": [
    "car01_hyb.com",
    "car02_hyb.com",
    "car03_hyb.com",
    "car04_hyb.com",
    "car05_hyb.com",
    "car06_hyb.com",
    "car07_hyb.com",
    "car08_hyb.com",
    "car09_hyb.com",
    "car10_hyb.com"
  ]
}
```

Adjust leading `0`s and `-2` according to the maximum length of `ID` in characters.

Comment: Good idea, but output is not quite right when ID=10. Does jq have anything like printf "%02d" ?

Comment: @glennjackman Not that I know of, but it can be implemented I guess. However OP's string template is `car0X_hyb.com`

Comment: For 10, OP wants `"car10_hyb.com"` with no leading zero

Comment: just note that solution should be according to my json example  , inside my json there are other strings as toyota , ford , etc, so you need to work on the example json

Comment: @King What do you think this website is? I'm not paid for this, I showed you how to do that, just to help

Comment: yes but you need to answer according to what I am asking , so your answer is partial

Comment: I am very sorry that you think that , but my question is very clearly  , and you not answered according to my question ( so if you downgrade my question - then I am also will do the same )

Comment: It's not that clear; 1. there is no sample input, 2. there is no sign of attempt made before asking the question

Comment: all the 3 json example are expected output , so why you think the examples not clear?

Comment: you need to give solution according to the json examples , what you did is just generate the json , while need to edit by jq the json as shown from example , hope its clear now

Comment: another thing - see the title of the topic - update json file and append name according to ID number ( this means to update the json , not as you did generate new json!!

Comment: jq doesn't have an internal mechanism for inplace modifications, you need to update the file by means of the shell; which you can find how to easily by googling. The code I posted is just PoC yes, but still applicable to and useful for your case. I don't **need** to do anything further, if anyone doesn't like it they can just downvote and move on

Comment: KingDavid - Please note that on SO, postings with separable questions are discouraged and with good reason. In the present case, I believe @oguzismail identified and addressed the essential question quite reasonably, so if that does not clear the roadblock you're facing, it would be appropriate either to explain the difficulty you're still having, or to ask a separate, focused question according to the usual [mcve] guidelines.  I have no idea who downvoted the "partial" answer, but downvoting a response just because it does not completely answer a multi-part question would be inappropriate.